# How to build a speech corpus for continuous speech?

Tags: speech-to-text, corpus

I am developing a speech corpus from audiobooks. I was able to collect recordings with their transcriptions but without timing information. Therefore I am looking for recent techniques to automatically build segments adapted to the development of ASR systems for large vocabulary continuous speech.

Thanks in an advance.

Comment: Sorry your question is not very clear to me: do you mean that you want to align the text from the transcript with the speech from the recording? Otherwise what kind of segmentation are you looking for?

Comment: Yes that's what I want, I'm not sure about the segmentation type but I think light alignment may be suitable for this kind of corpus.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this problem but I found these links which might help: [an explanation with links to various tools](https://techfirst.medium.com/forced-alignment-how-to-match-audio-with-a-transcript-via-machine-learning-dd19da8c0f04) and [another online tool here](https://www.clarin-d.net/en/analysing/alignment-of-transcription-and-speech-signals).

Comment: Thank you anyway @Erwan